# sorting and rearranging an array of hashes based on multiple conditions

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, hash

I'm trying to sort an array based on 3 different criteria. Let's say I have an array of hashes like this:

```
a = [
    { "name" => "X", "year" => "2013-08"},
    { "name" => "A", "year" => "2017-01"},
    { "name" => "X", "year" => "2000-08"},
    { "name" => "B", "year" => "2018-05"},
    { "name" => "D", "year" => "2016-04"},
    { "name" => "C", "year" => "2016-04"}
]
```

I would like to sort all elements first by "year" in descending order, then by "name" in ascending order, then move all elements matching a given name to the beginning of the array, while still respecting the "year" order. For this example, let's say I'm looking for elements with a "name" value of "X". So the output I'm looking for would be:

```
{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"}
{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"}
{"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"}
{"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"}
{"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}
{"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}
```

So everything is in descending order of "year", then ascending order of "name", then all hashes where "name" == "X" moved to the top, still sorted by "year".

I took care of the ascending/descending sorting by doing this:

```
a.sort { |a,b| [b["year"], a["name"]] <=> [a["year"], b["name"]] }
```

But this only handles the first 2 criteria of what I need. I tried something like this afterward:

```
top = []
a.each { |x| top << x if x["name"] == "X" }
a.delete_if { |x| x["name"] == "X"}
a.unshift(top)
```

which does produce the desired output, but is obviously clunky and doesn't seem like the best way to be doing things. Is there a faster, more efficient way to do what I'm trying to do?

(FYI, the year values are strings and I can't convert them into integers. I simplified the values here, but the data I'm pulling from actually appends a series of other characters and symbols at the end of each value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another option using what you already have as a base (Since you were basically all the way there)

```
a = [
  { "name" => "X", "year" => "2013-08"},
  { "name" => "A", "year" => "2017-01"},
  { "name" => "X", "year" => "2000-08"},
  { "name" => "B", "year" => "2018-05"},
  { "name" => "D", "year" => "2016-04"},
  { "name" => "C", "year" => "2016-04"}
]


a.sort do  |a,b| 
  a_ord, b_ord = [a,b].map {|e| e["name"] == "X" ? 0 : 1 }
  [a_ord,b["year"],a["name"] ] <=> [b_ord, a["year"],b["name"]]
end
```

Here we just make sure that "X" is always in front by assigning it a 0 and everything else a 1. Then since 0 and 0 would be equivalent X will fall back to the same logic you already have applied as will all the others. We can make this a bit fancier as:

```
a.sort do  |a,b| 
  [a,b].map {|e| e["name"] == "X" ? 0 : 1 }.zip(
    [b["year"],a["year"]],[a["name"],b["name"]]
  ).reduce(:<=>)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

`sort` is not the thing you want to use if you have consistent sort criteria. The faster method is `sort_by`:

```
a.sort_by { |e| [ e["year"], e["name"] ] }
```

Since you want them in reverse order:

```
a.sort_by { |e| [ e["year"], e["name"] ] }.reverse
```

Where in effect that sorts each element in the array based on the converted form expressed in the block, then sorts based on those instead. This conversion is done once and once only, and this is a lot less messy than the `sort` method which must perform that conversion each time a comparison is made.

Now if you want to sort the "X" entries to the top you can easily add that as an additional criteria:

```
a.sort_by { |e| [ e["name"] == "X" ? 1 : 0, e["year"], e["name"] ] }.reverse
```

So that gets you to where you want to be.

The nice thing about `sort_by` is you can usually express really complicated sorting logic as a series of elements in an array. Provided each element is Comparable it all works out.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I actually had tried using `sort_by` along with `reverse`, but the problem is that I want only the "year" to be reversed, not the "name" (i.e. descending years, but ascending names). So if two elements have the same "year", they will be listed alphabetically. Is there a way to apply the `reverse` exclusively to the `e["year"]` part?

Comment: For `e["name"] != "X"`, the sorting is to be done by decreasing values of `e["year"]` with ties broken by *increasing* values of `e["name"]`. You have sorted on decreasing values of both, so that the the sorted array ends, `[... {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}, {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}]`, which is the opposite of the order desired.

Comment: Since your "year" is mostly numerical, you could try `-e["year"].sub(/\-/, '').to_i` as the sort key, negating it to reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [
  {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"},
  {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"},
  {"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"},
  {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"},
  {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"},
  {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"},
]
```

When parts of an array are to be sorted differently than other parts of the array, I find it beneficial to partition the array into the associated parts, sort each part separately, then combine the results of those sorts. Not only is this approach generally easy for readers to follow, but it simplifies testing and tends to be at least as efficient as performing a single, more complex sort. Here, we would partition the array into two parts.

```
x, non_x = arr.partition { |h| h["name"] == 'X' }
  #=> [[{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"}, {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"}],
  #    [{"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"}, {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"},
  #     {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}, {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}]]
```

Sorting the array `x` is easy.

```
sorted_x = x.sort_by { |h| h["year"] }.reverse
  #=> [{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"}, {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"}]
```

Sorting `non_x` is a more complex because it is to be sorted by *decreasing* order of the values of `"year"`, with ties to be broken by the values of `"name"`, in *increasing* order. In this situation we can always use [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort).

```
non_x.sort do |g,h|
  case g["year"] <=> h["year"]
  when -1
    1
  when 1
    -1
  when 0
    (g["name"] < h["name"]) ? -1 : 1
  end
end
  #=> [{"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"}, {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"},
  #    {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}, {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}]
```

With a bit of effort we could alternatively use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). Given a hash `h`, we would need to sort on either

```
[h["year"], f(h["name"])].reverse
```

where `f` is a method that causes `h["name"]` to be sorted in decreasing order, or (note no `.reverse` in the following)

```
[f(h["year"]), h["name"]]
```

where `f` is a method that causes `h["year"]` to be sorted in decreasing order. The latter is the easier of the two to implement. We could use the following method.

```
def year_str_to_int(year_str)
  yr, mon = year_str.split('-').map(&:to_i)
  12 * yr + mon
end
```

This allows us to sort `non_x` as desired:

```
sorted_non_x = non_x.sort_by { |h| [-year_str_to_int(h["year"]), h["name"]] }
  #=> [{"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"}, {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"},
  #    {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}, {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}]
```

We now simply combine the two sorted partitions.

```
sorted_x.concat(sorted_non_x)
  #=> [{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"}, {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"},
  #    {"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"}, {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"}, 
  #    {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"}, {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own comparator by implementing the comparable logic for your objects like so:

```
require 'pp'

a = [
    { "name" => "X", "year" => "2013-08"},
    { "name" => "A", "year" => "2017-01"},
    { "name" => "X", "year" => "2000-08"},
    { "name" => "B", "year" => "2018-05"},
    { "name" => "D", "year" => "2016-04"},
    { "name" => "C", "year" => "2016-04"}
]

class NameYearSorter
  attr_reader :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def name
    value['name']
  end

  def year
    value['year']
  end

  def <=>(other)
    if self.name != 'X' && other.name != 'X'
      if self.year == other.year
        self.name <=> other.name
      else
        self.year > other.year ? -1 : 0
      end
    elsif self.name == 'X' && other.name != 'X'
      -1
    elsif other.name == 'X' && self.name != 'X'
      0   
    elsif self.name == other.name
      other.year > self.year ? 0 : -1
    end
  end
end

sortable = a.map{ |v| NameYearSorter.new(v) }
pp sortable.sort.map(&:value)

# Output:
#=> [{"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2013-08"},
#=>  {"name"=>"X", "year"=>"2000-08"},
#=>  {"name"=>"B", "year"=>"2018-05"},
#=>  {"name"=>"A", "year"=>"2017-01"},
#=>  {"name"=>"C", "year"=>"2016-04"},
#=>  {"name"=>"D", "year"=>"2016-04"}]
```